# How to use the mod function on LISPS using control structures

Tags: if-statement, lisp, modulo

I am new to LISP, is there a way of using `mod` with control structures, `if` statements.

for instance having `(if (mod 4 2) (+ 2 2) (- 9 2))`. 
What does the expression return, `0`, `nil`, `T`?

Comment: What do you mean by "parameter"? do you have a Lisp environment where you can test things, like CCL, SBCL, CLISP,  or maybe a Scheme/Racket environment? What source of documentation do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lisp, the only [false](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_f.htm#false) value is [`nil`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_nil.htm), so `0` is [true](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_t.htm#true).
Thus `(mod 4 2)` returns 0 which is true which means that

```
(if (mod 4 2)
    (+ 2 2)
    (- 9 2))
```

returns 4, while

```
(if (/= 0 (mod 4 2))
    (+ 2 2)
    (- 9 2))
```

returns 7.

Comment: I wrote the second if statement and it threw an error

Comment: @mark.b: you need to copy and paste the error and also specify your environment as coredump requested.